# To find the Most Powerful Test (MP test) of the given hypothesis problem

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-power, neyman-pearson-lemma

A friend of mine asked me the [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH7DD.png) below on testing:

> Let $X$ be a single observation from one or other member of the family $\{f_0(x),f_1(x)\}$ where
>
> $$f_0(x)=\frac{1}{2^{x+1}}\mathbf1_{x\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}}$$
>
> $$f_1(x)=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x\mathbf1_{x\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}}$$
>
> Find a MP test of $H_0:X\sim f_0(x)$ against $H_1:X\sim f_1(x)$ at level $\alpha=0.05$.

**My approach:**

I tried to solve this sum using Neyman-Pearson Lemma (NP Lemma).

[image]

[image]

But I am not sure if I'm correct. Please help me and let me know.

Comment: The answer is correct. Please learn some basic [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math here as that would generate greater response.

Comment: Thank you..It was of great help to know this..Surely would try to learn MathJax..